# Rails assets still being served in single file in development

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

In my development.rb I have

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.compress = false
```

However my assets are being served in single files"

```
images/application.js
javascripts/application.css
```

I have deleted the cache files from tmp/cache & restarted the server but assets are still served in a single file (not compressed by the way).

I'm running Rails 3.2.13.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Have you previously pre-compiled your assets? Check to see if there is an application.js and application.css in your public/assets folder, and if so rm -rf public/assets

Comment: Nope. there isn't a public/assets folder. I think i deleted it already while trying to fix this

Comment: what does appending in the URL ?debug_assets=true give you?